# Rails routes with constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to catch UTF-8 URL. Normally, using constraints this works well. For the URL: `/international-delight-iced-coffee/` the route works:

```
match ":post_name", :constraints => { :post_name => /.+/}}
```

All is well here. Where it fails is when I need to use advanced constraints:

```
match ":post_name", :constraints => Post.new

# inside Post.rb
self.matches?(request)
  puts ">>>> Arrived at matches!"
  Post.find_by_name(request.path_parameters[:post_name])
end
```

`self.matches` never gets called. Any idea how to make the constraint catch?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need controller/action that you want the match to hit (below with the `to` param).

I've got something like this:

```
match "/:vanity", to: 'vanity#routing', constraints: RoutingConstraint.new
```

and my `RoutingConstraint#matches?` method *is* getting hit.

I tried this with your UTF-8 url and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.matches?` method is a class method, but you're passing `Post.new` as the constraint. Either replace `Post.new` with `Post`, or remove `self.` form the method definition.